# What is the widest range 9 speed cassette?

Tags: mountain-bike, cassette

My commuter rig is an old trek mountain bike that I've converted to fixed gear with an ENO hub/crankset.  I am thinking about going geared for the winter.  I have a rear wheel that I built last year and never used (found the eccentric wheel on craigslist around the same time), an SLX rear derailleur and an LX shifter.  Looking for a wide range cassette so I can take the bike offroad a bit more often, but I'm hoping to keep my 42t chainring on.  I'm willing to take the risk that the ENO ring can work with a 9 speed chain.

The best I've found is a shimano CS-HG61 (12-36) which I think would be more than enough, but if there's anything bigger available I'd like to know.  Not interested in mods/adapters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looking to go faster on the flats you can find multiple cassette models with a range of 11-34. If you are looking for more "granny" on the hills, 12-36 is the best you are going to find out of the box without swapping out the low ring. ([Sheldon Brown](http://sheldonbrown.com/k9.shtml))

That said, on most 9-speed cassettes I have seen, the smallest ring or two are not riveted to the body, so you could easily swap the 12 out for an 11 to get that much more range.

Comment: Thanks - I thought this was the case but wanted to be sure.  Looking for more granny, I'm used to pushing 42/17 and doubt I'll go above that too often (or below for that matter, but I figure I'll appreciate it on snowy days).